Cloning Multiple repos on Ec2 | .ssh config error
Problem statement : Clone 2 repos from Github
Actions Taken :

Created 2 ssh keys and added to corresponding repos's deploy keys.
Create a config file in Home/Ubuntu/.ssh folder

      Host aimer-ui github.com
        HostName github.com
        IdentityFile /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_new.pub
            
     
    
       Host aimer-service github.com
         HostName github.com
         IdentityFile /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Error Coming on Cloning :
Cloning into 'aimer-ui'...
Load key "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_new.pub": error in libcrypto
Load key "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": Permission denied
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-44-226:~$ git clone git@github.com:BeA-Brand/aimer-service.git
Cloning into 'aimer-service'...
Load key "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa_new.pub": error in libcrypto
Load key "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa.pub": Permission denied
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

My Observation : Same ssh being used in cloning the repos. But in that case, atleast one repo would have worked.

You are specifying public keys for the IdentityFile.  You should be specifying their private counterpart.

I see a few things wrong here.
First: You went to the trouble of setting up ~/.ssh/config with key-specific hostnames, and then you didn't use those key-specific hostnames. Your commands need to be git clone git@aimer-service:BeA-Brand/aimer-service.git and git clone git@aimer-ui:BeA-Brand/aimer-ui.git (or whatever the correct path is for that one).
As @erik258 pointed out in the comments, your ~/.ssh/config needs the private keys. Take off the .pub endings.
You can potentially troubleshoot the libcrypto issue with ssh -Tv git@aimer-ui - GitHub will not give you shell, but the verbose output should be helpful in determining what's wrong with the key.
You can check the permissions and ownership on /home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa with ls -la /home/ubuntu/.ssh. id_rsa needs to have mode 0600; id_rsa.pub can have mode 0644; the folder needs mode 1700; and all of them need to be owned by the ubuntu user.
